# How do I make sure that Glide won't downsample my image?

Tags: android, android-glide

It's not `.dontTransform()`. Anyone know what method to call to remove the downsampling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .dontTransform()
    .load(your_url_here)
    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
    .into(your_image_view);
```

Comment: i don't know the size but i need the full sized image